# What is colon:message `:message` in form

Tags: html, forms, laravel

I want to know more about how :message works. I see in the official docs how to use it but I don't understand where the value is set and how it becomes a unique variable for each input. I can't it find it in the API either.

```
 <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('first_name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name">
  {{ $errors->first('first_name', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') }}
</div>
```

where can I find more information about `:message`. what does the `:` signify and so on? I can't google it. So I hope someone can direct me to a reference.

Comment: Actually I think it is just for replacement. Prepared statement-style

Comment: @kingkero OP *probably* found this at https://github.com/adamwathan/bootforms/blob/master/readme.md - *most likely*. and/or http://mocksource.com/copy_ApplicationCode/app/storage/views/7332aac3077d08b09b944c4770f8d3a1 - Seems to be related to Laravel.

Comment: Yes I am working with Laravel. I will update tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you pass in as second argument to `first()` is the format of the error message. As mentioned in the  comments, the `:message` part gets replaced by the actual error message.

It all happens inside the [`MessageBag` class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.php)

You call `first()`. Inside the function `$this->get()` gets called

```
$messages = is_null($key) ? $this->all($format) : $this->get($key, $format);
```

Inside get it will check if there's a message for the passed key and if positive `$this->transform()` will be called

```
if (array_key_exists($key, $this->messages))
{
    return $this->transform($this->messages[$key], $format, $key);
}
```

Now it finally gets interesting. Within `transform`, The keywords `:message` and `:key` will be replaced with the actual message and the actual key (`$format` is the string you passed in at the beginning `'<p class="help-block">:message</p>'`)

```
$replace = array(':message', ':key');

$message = str_replace($replace, array($message, $messageKey), $format);
```